# What is meaning of "parallel park"

Tags: expressions

This is part of film script and it goes like this.

> Yeah. I'm right here.
>
> I... You know what? I need to parallel park and I'm not on my
>   earpiece.

In this script, she's driving and arriving to a friend's house.
The title of film is "Coherence".

I don't get it well this, please let me understand this.

Comment: Its a standard expression. [***Parallel parking***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_parking)

Comment: This term appears in pretty much every modern dictionary (Oxford, Cambridge, MW, TFD, Wiki...). Is there something about the dictionary definition you find confusing?

Comment: @EsotericScreenName, No, I did not think of finding it as one word. I think parallel is a verb and park is a parking lot. There comes my confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is when you park parallel to the road, like so:

[image]

It is harder to parallel park than it is to pull into a regular parking place, so I would assume what she means is "I have to set my phone down so I can concentrate on not hitting the cars in front of or behind me."

Comment: ah.. that's it. I totally got it. I wondered why she said the earpiece.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @DJMcMayhem You'd make a fantastic teacher. Showing so much more helpful than explaining! : )

Comment: Haha, thanks. I actually just got the gif from user 3169's link. So very little effort on my part.